# Mongoimport csv (>500K rows/documents) error, import csv by chunks to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoimport

**How would we import a table that has more than 500K rows? If importing by chunks would be the solution, is there a tutorial on importing chunks of csv data to mongodb?**

I tried to import a csv file, containing 2,710,000 rows, using the following command:

```
mongoimport -d test -c transact --type csv --file transact.csv --headerline
```

It gives an error:

```
2015-11-02T12:44:35.420-0500    connected to: localhost
2015-11-02T12:44:38.419-0500    [........................] test.transact
11.7 MB/397.5 MB (2.9%)
2015-11-02T12:44:41.414-0500    [#.......................] test.transact
22.1 MB/397.5 MB (5.6%)
2015-11-02T12:44:44.413-0500    [##......................] test.transact
33.8 MB/397.5 MB (8.5%)
2015-11-02T12:44:47.414-0500    [##......................] test.transact
44.0 MB/397.5 MB (11.1%)
2015-11-02T12:44:50.420-0500    [###.....................] test.transact
55.3 MB/397.5 MB (13.9%)
2015-11-02T12:44:53.413-0500    [###.....................] test.transact
66.1 MB/397.5 MB (16.6%)
2015-11-02T12:44:55.962-0500    [####....................] test.transact
73.5 MB/397.5 MB (18.5%)
2015-11-02T12:45:07.501-0500    Failed: read error on entry #500899: line 500900
, column 140: extraneous " in field
2015-11-02T12:45:07.502-0500    imported 500000 documents
```

How come only 500K can be loaded into mongodb?
I looked online:

> Maximum Number of Documents Per Chunk to Migrate
>
> MongoDB cannot move a chunk if the number of documents in the chunk exceeds either **250000** documents or 1.3 times the number of average sized documents that the maximum chunk size can hold.

source:
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/

I also happened to run into a blog of a developer who also ran into similar issue:

> Seriously? Seriously? MongoDB dies after about **500,000** documents, silently corrupting my data, not issuing any warnings and then refusing to let me even read it? I’ve never seen such broken behaviour in any other piece of software I’ve used. I went back to the channel, seething (I can’t imagine the guys in there were very happy with providing free support to an angry person, but they were helpful nonetheless), and detailed my predicament. Obviously, the solution would be to reformat my server and install a 64-bit OS if I wanted to have more than 500k documents in the database.

source:
http://www.stavros.io/posts/my-experience-with-using-mongodb-for-great-science/

How would we import a table that has more than 500K rows? If importing by chunks would be the solution, is there a tutorial on importing chunks of csv data to mongodb?

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried using CSV import, but I can assure you that MongoDB can handle *many* more documents. I manage clusters which have collections exceeding 200M docs.

You are mixing concepts here. A [chunk](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-chunk) is a logical unit used to manage a [sharded cluster](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-sharded-cluster) and can have an arbitrary size. However, when exceeding certain thresholds, it is considered a [Jumbo-Chunk](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-chunk-migration/#jumbo-chunks) and can not be migrated from one shard to another to balance the data stored on each cluster node. Chunk thresholds have absolutely nothing to do with the maximum data a MongoDB instance can hold.

And, forgive my french, that guy you are quoting knows little to nothing about the matter he is talking about, documenting his own inability for the most simple task nor does he seem to be able to [read the docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#what-are-the-limitations-of-32-bit-versions-of-mongodb). What do we actually have? A guy ranting about things he does not know anything about and too lazy to properly prepare for his fragging **M**Sc. Frankly, I am asking myself how he got his BSc, the first place. That guy ran a *development version* of a branch *discouraged for production* and complains about corrupted data (of which he should have a backup, anyway, given the fact that he is a ["Systems Administrator and IT-Manager"](http://resume.stavros.io))… I would trust that information as far as I can throw the Empire State Building. ;)

Back to your problem:
You might have fallen into the same trap: Using a 32-bit version of MongoDB except for very small tests or proofs-of-concept is simply not advised. Quite the contrary:

> When running a 32-bit build of MongoDB, the total storage size for the server, including data and indexes, is 2 gigabytes. **For this reason, do not deploy MongoDB to production on 32-bit machines.**

So, first make sure that you do **not** run a 32-bit version of MongoDB. Change if necessary.

When you are running a 64-bit version of MongoDB, proceed.

The second thing you can do is to make absolutely positively sure that line 500900 is not corrupted. Simply print it out with

```
sed -n "500900p" your.csv
```

then double and triple check the output. In case you still have problems, please add a new question with the output of above `sed` command on http://dba.stackoverflow.com